# Hotel Reservation for Germany

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, hotels

I am brazilian, and I will be in Germany for holydays for about 22 days.

I already know as Brazilian, I don't need a visa to enter Germany, but there still are some requirements such as proof of money and hotel reservation.

Will a reservation of booking.com do the trick? I intend to pay after my staying, I will be in 3 cities in Germany, and would like to pay after I check out, in case I change my mind and go to somewhere else in Europe or Germany.

***PS.: I am also taking 1000 EUR and credit cards with me.***

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine. But really, they can ask about financial means, accommodation, etc. but in most cases it will just be brief interview. Do not volunteer everything immediately, it might look awkward. Just be genuine and answer the questions truthfully and everything should go well.